# At least one of each gender

Tags: probability

A class of 22 students consists of 12 girls and 10 boys. The class selects 3 students for student council. What is the probability that at least one of each gender is on student council?

Comment: welcome to MSE!, so what have you tried so far in solving this problem?

Comment: What have you tried?  Where did you run into difficulties?  Can you answer a related question with, say, just five students?

Comment: the fact that it is two genders, not just one. At least one of each gender.. is where i'm struggling.

Comment: The answer depends on a lot of information that hasn't been given. How popular are each of the $22$ candidates? Are any of the voters prejudiced against girls? Are bribes in play? And so on.

Answer (score 1):

number of groups of three with at least one of each gender= total number of groups of three - number of groups of three made up of people with the same gender= $\binom{22}{3}-\binom{12}{3}-\binom{10}{3}$; also the total number of groups of three is $\binom{22}{3}$ thus $P=\frac{\binom{22}{3}-\binom{12}{3}-\binom{10}{3}}{\binom{22}{3}}=\frac{60}{77}\approx 78$%

Answer (score 1):

Consider the complement - what is the probability that all 3 students are of the same gender?
$P(\textrm{All girls}) = \frac{12}{22}\times\frac{11}{21}\times\frac{10}{20}=\frac{1}{7}$
$P(\textrm{All boys}) = \frac{10}{22}\times\frac{9}{21}\times\frac{8}{20}=\frac{6}{77}$
Thus, the probability is $1-(\frac{1}{7}+\frac{6}{77})=\frac{60}{77}\approx78\%$

Comment: amazing. I see it now. thank you.

Comment: my pleasure. Cheers!